# How to insert comment in desired position in XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am finding elements from XML1 in XML2 and after that i want to insert one comment
XML1 is:

```
<Price>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <Amount>102</Amount>
    <Amount>103</Amount>
</Price>
```

and XML2 is:

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
```

Output XML i want is following where I want to insert a comment above Price if the value is matching from price/amount from XML2:

```
<List>
    <Item>
      <!--important-->
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
```

After getting help from this forum I tried coding like this:

```
xml1 = etree.parse('C:/Python/XML1.xml')
xml2 = etree.parse('C:/Python/XML2.xml')
for am in xml1.xpath('//Price/Id/text()'):
    x = xml2.xpath(f'//List/Item/Price[./Amount/text()="{am}"]')
    if len(x)>0:
        root = xml2.find('.//List/Item/Price')
        root.insert(1, etree.Comment('important'))
        etree.dump(root)
with open('C:/Python/output.xml','w') as f:
    f.write(etree.Comment(root))
```

I am not able to get proper output xml
I am getting error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

Grateful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml1 = '''<Price>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <Amount>102</Amount>
    <Amount>103</Amount>
</Price>'''

xml2 = ''' <List>
    <Item>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
'''

root1 = ET.fromstring(xml1)
root2 = ET.fromstring(xml2)
amounts = set(e.text for e in root1.findall('.//Amount'))
for item in root2.findall('.//Item'):
    prices = item.findall('.//Price')
    for price in prices:
        amount = price.find('Amount').text
        if amount in amounts:
            item.insert(0, ET.Comment('Important'))
ET.dump(root2)
```

output

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <!--Important-->
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
         <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to compare across documents and traverse multiple nodes with conditional logic to add comment, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Python's `lxml` library can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. Also, XSLT maintains the `document` function to parse from other documents.

Specifically, below XSLT runs the identity transform to copy document as is and then conditionally adds comment before `<Price>` element. Notice XSLT references the `First_Document.xml` and Python references the `Second_Document.xml`. Be sure file in `document()` is in same location to second document.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- UPDATE Item NODES -->
    <xsl:template match="Item">
     <xsl:copy>
       <!-- MAP THROUGH Price NODES -->
       <xsl:for-each select="Price">
         <!-- CONDITIONALLY ADD COMMENT -->
         <xsl:variable name="curr_amount" select="Amount"/>
         <xsl:if test="document('First_Document.xml')/Price/Amount = $curr_amount">
           <xsl:comment>important</xsl:comment>
         </xsl:if>
         <!-- ALWAYS RE-WRITE Price NODES -->         
         <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

# LOAD XML AND XSLT
xml = etree.parse("Second_Document.xml")
xsl = etree.parse("My_StyleSheet.xsl")

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transformer = etree.XSLT(xsl)
result = transformer(xml)

# SAVE TRANSFORMATION TO FILE
result.write_output("Output.xml")
```

**Output**

```xml
<List>
  <Item>
    <!--important-->
    <Price>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
      <Next_Item>
        <Name>Apple</Name>
      </Next_Item>
      <Next_Item>
        <Name>Orange</Name>
      </Next_Item>
    </Price>
    <Price>
      <Amount>200</Amount>
      <Next_Item>
        <Name>Apple</Name>
      </Next_Item>
      <Next_Item>
        <Name>Orange</Name>
      </Next_Item>
    </Price>
  </Item>
</List>
```